# How to apply ifnull inside case when statement in SQL [BQ]?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

How to apply the ifnull statement inside case when to avoid creating separate 'field_1' columns in the table?
input:

[image]

output:

[image]

```
SELECT ifnull(field_1, 'other'), count(*),
        case when field_1 = 'done'
        and market in ('usa', 'ca')
        and date < TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01')
        then
        'historical'
        else field_1 end as field_1
     FROM `tablename` 
     group by 1,3
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Hi, it's a big query

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ to make things clearer. I.e. a [mcve]. (Use properly formatted text, not images or links.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IS NULL` in the conditional statement like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE  
    WHEN field_1 = 'done' AND market IN ('usa', 'ca') AND date < TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01') THEN 'historical'
    WHEN field_1 IS NULL THEN 'other'
    ELSE field_1
  END AS field_1
FROM your_table
```